# Prove using Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Prove using Fermat's Little Theorem that if $p\in \mathbb{P}$ then:
$$p \mid\left(\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{p}\underbrace{2\ldots2}_{p}\ldots\underbrace{9\ldots9}_{p} - 123456789  \right)$$

Comment: Hint: can u see ${a^p \equiv  a (mod p)}$ in the equation?

Comment: Not really. Do you mean that 123456789≡1..12..2..9..9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume $p \neq 3$. (I leave $p = 3$ up to you. Use the divisibility test.)
By Fermat's Little Theorem, we have $10^p \equiv 10 \bmod p$.

Let $k = \underbrace{1\ldots1}_{p}$. Then,
$$k = 1 + 10 + \cdots + 10^{p-1} = \frac{10^p - 1}{9} \equiv \dfrac{10 - 1}{9} \equiv 1 \bmod p.$$
(Note that $p \neq 3$ and thus, $9^{-1}$ makes sense.)

Now, let
$$N = \underbrace{1\ldots1}_{p}\underbrace{2\ldots2}_{p}\ldots\underbrace{9\ldots9}_{p} = k\cdot10^{8p} + 2k\cdot10^{7p} + \cdots + 9k.$$

Going modulo $p$, we get
$$N \equiv k\cdot10^8 + 2k\cdot10^7 + \cdots + 9k \bmod p.$$

Using $k \equiv 1 \bmod p$ gives

$$N \equiv 10^8 + 2\cdot10^7 + \cdots + 9 \equiv 123456789 \bmod p.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why did you assume that 10^p≡10 mod p?

Comment: @Ayt: You're welcome. That's how I went from $10^{8p}, \ldots, 10^p$ to $10^8, \ldots, 10$. (The equation after "Going modulo $p$".) I also used it in concluding that $(10^p - 1)/9 \equiv (10 - 1)/9$.

Comment: I see, but why is it true?

Comment: @Ayt: Do you know what Fermat's little theorem is?

Comment: Oh god, I understand now...  Thanks again!

Comment: @Ayt: No worries. Actually, your comment made me realise that the version of FLT that I'm using does not require $10$ to be coprime to $p$. So my argument works for $p = 2, 5$ as well. Will edit that.